# SSIS package taking a very long time to execute

Tags: ssis

I have a package that does a row by row update of values. When i run this though the debug mode (opening the solution and pressing 'play') it takes about 2 mins. However when i try to run it by clicking thre dtsx, it takes about 3 hours.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Abhi

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how long it is taking to run each update?  Is it using OLEDB Destinations or T-SQL commands?  You could add a script task to raise a Dts.Events.OnInformation event to help identify the bottleneck.

Any reason you can't batch up the updates?  Maybe load a staging table and then run a single update command at the end?